# Checkstyle multiple files SuppressionFilter

Tags: java, checkstyle

I want to have multiple suppression files for Checkstyle. Which means, that I'll have 2 separate files with separate suppression rules:

The way to add 1 file is this is to add this in the rules:

```
<module name="SuppressionFilter">
    <property name="file" value="docs/suppressions.xml"/>
</module>
```

What I want to achieve is: (This isn't legal syntax)

```
<module name="SuppressionFilter">
    <property name="file" value="docs/suppressions-1.xml"/>
    <property name="file" value="docs/suppressions-2.xml"/>
</module>
```

I tried using 2 separate SuppressionFilters, but this seems to overwrite the first with the second.

What I mean is:

```
<module name="SuppressionFilter">
    <property name="file" value="docs/suppressions-1.xml"/>
</module>

<module name="SuppressionFilter">
    <property name="file" value="docs/suppressions-2.xml"/>
</module>
```

If done as above, it will only use suppressions-2.xml

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Your option 2 is good, just add the module twice:

```xml
<module name="SuppressionFilter">
    <property name="file" value="docs/suppressions-1.xml"/>
</module>
<module name="SuppressionFilter">
    <property name="file" value="docs/suppressions-2.xml"/>
</module>
```

Both suppressions will be active, so anything that is suppressed in either file will be suppressed.

If your *suppressions-1.xml* is not working, it would be a problem in that file.

Comment: Hi, I tried this multiple times, but this isn't working.

Comment: Well I use this all the time, so your problem must be something else, e.g. non-ascii character in a comment in *suppressions-1.xml* or something. We'd need more info from you about the error, plus a way to reproduce.